# Make popup appear only once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, web

I am writing a website using an internal tool which allows the use of HTML, JavaScript, JQuery and basic Ruby on Rails.

I have a popup which appears on the screen in the same manner as the one shown in this codebox:

[Link to codebox.](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/audcf)

Currently, this pops up every time the user loads the page. The behaviour I would like is for it to pop up for a user once, then when they navigate back to the page it should no longer display.

Is it possible to achieve this?

HTML :

```
<div id="hover"></div>
  <div id="popup">
    <div id="close">X</div>
      <a href="https://www.stackoverflow.com" class="twitter-follow-button" data-show-count="false" data-lang="it">Halp StackOverflow, I only want this to pop up once.</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  //chiusura al click sulla parte scura
  $("#hover").click(function(){
        $(this).fadeOut();
    $("#popup").fadeOut();
    });

  //chiusura al click sul pulsante
  $("#close").click(function(){
        $("#hover").fadeOut();
    $("#popup").fadeOut();
    });

});
```

Comment: You can use cookies or localstorage for this, saving the fact that user has already visited this page.

Comment: using javascript its not feasible. probably what you are looking for is sessions or cookies.

Comment: Your best bet is to go with cookies.

Comment: @Regent Can I use JavaScript for this? I think Ruby would be best, but the internal tool I am using only supports a restrictive set of Ruby operations so I am not sure if this will work unfortunately.

Comment: @Darren Can you point me to any resources on how I would do this please? I am rather new to Ruby on rails and trying to get my head around it. Thanks very much.

Comment: @SimonKiely yes, localStorage (this is client-side storage) is mantained using JavaScript. Take a look at [docs](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp).

Comment: @SimonKiely I've just thrown together an answer with the way I've done it in the past, there are cleaner methods out there but the answer works faultlessly :)

Comment: if you're using auth and have a sessions controller, you could save to the session as a boolean then just add a quick unless session[:foo] or w/e to the popup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on my comment, you'd use javascript to set the cookie.
The only downfall to this is that it isn't persistent, meaning that if the visitor deletes his history & cookies and all that jazz, the pop **will** show up again.

Basically you'd have some code that'd check if there was a cookie set, and if it isn't set, show the popup and then set the cookie.

```
if (!CHECK_COOKIE(GET_COOKIE(CUSTOM_COOKIE_NAME))) {
    // generate the popup html
    // and append it to the DOM

    // now you set the cookie (because it wasn't set before)
    setTimeout("SET_COOKIE(365)", 1000);
}
```

I'll include the cookie functions from above to give you an idea of how you'd go about them.

First we'll start with the cookie check function:
    // c in this function is the cookie
    var cookie_check = function(c) {
        if (c == null || c == "") {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

Now the cookie fetch function (this function basically fetches the cookie for the supplied `name` param):

```
var cookie_get = function(name) {
        if (document.cookie.length > 0) {
            c_start = document.cookie.indexOf(name + "=");
            if (c_start != -1) {
                c_start = c_start + name.length + 1;
                c_end = document.cookie.indexOf(";", c_start);
                if (c_end == -1) {
                    c_end = document.cookie.length;
                }
                return unescape(document.cookie.substring(c_start, c_end));
            }
        }
        return "";
    }
```

And last but not least, the cookie setter:

```
var cookie_set = function(expiredays, cookie_name, value) {
        var exp = new Date();
        exp.setDate(exp.getDate() + expiredays);
        // set cookie
        document.cookie = name + '=' + value + ';path=/' + ((expiredays == null || expiredays == 0) ? '' : ';expires=' + exp.toGMTString());
    }
```

And to wrap that off, here's a simple example for you :)

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/xyhzvm61/)

---

<sup>*The cookie name in the jsfiddle demo above doesn't get set because they (JSFiddle)* set the cookie name to `result`, but check the value and you'll see a difference. :)</sup>